# Access RDS from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, mysql, amazon-rds

I am having a hard time figuring out how to give an ec2 instance access to an RDS instance in order to perform a mysqldump.

Do I need to add a security group that allows the ec2 instance access to that server? I tried this using the RDS endpoint and it would not allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify RDS instance's security group and allow access to EC2 instance (by adding its IP address or security group, TCP, port 3306).
Of course, you will also need the endpoint, username, and password.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html

Comment: got it thanks...I needed the private IM address and not the RDS endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue accessing RDS from my local and if it's possible - set it to publicly accessible:

RDS instance => Details => modify

public access

Comment: Note that this will make your database accessible from anybody on the Internet who manages to find the IP address. If you choose to do this, pick a username and password for your database that are not easily guessable or you risk your data being compromised.